# 'request hooks' for Owasp ZAP

Tags: owasp, zap

Is there a way I can trigger some action once a particular request is issued in ZAP?
For example, I want to send a POST request to an endpoint whenever there is a login/logout request.

Environment: I'm using a ZAP docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use an [HTTP Sender](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/main/httpsender) script - that will get invoked on every request and response sent or proxied through ZAP. You can test for your login/logout request and then send you POST request.
To add scripts to ZAP from the command line see [this FAQ](https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-you-add-a-script-to-zap-from-the-command-line/).